# Filter results to based on specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ES6 and ReactJS. I need some help to filter out the results in array, in a way, where I can check if the index matches, only then call the function `createOptions()`.

Actual code :

```
const newArr = items
    .filter(this.isEligible(selectedIndex))
    .filter((item, index) => this.createOptions(item, index, selectedItem));
```

Need something like(expected)):

```
const newArr = items
    .filter(this.isEligible(selectedIndex))
    .filter((item, selectedIndex) => selectedIndex || selectedIndex+ 2 ? this.createOptions(item, selectedIndex, selectedItem));
```

Here, I need to filter out the results when the `index` equals `selectedIndex` or `selectedIndex+2`, then call `createOptions(item, index, selectedItem);`

But, I'm getting some syntax error while trying to do that. 
Could you please help me fix that?

Comment: Could you show the Array you're starting with (presumably `items`) and the Array (`newArr`) that you want to end up with? That way we can probably see what needs to be done, rather than deciphering intent from your posted 'expected' code and description.

Comment: _But, I'm getting some syntax error while trying to do that._ So what is the error?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected : (32:209)

Comment: You are using a ternary operation without adding the `else` part of it. It goes like, `a = condition? b : c`. You haven't added what value to be returned if `selectedIndex|| selectedIndex+ 2` condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to access item at specific index in array, you don't need to filter that array. Just access it by bracket notation:

```
const itemAtIndex = items[selectedIndex]
const itemAtIndexPlusTwo = items[selectedIndex + 2]
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  It's a syntax error.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it may address the question. OP is obviously struggling with javascript syntax and my best guess is that he wants to access item in array